# How to display Eclipse console error into my alert dialog?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, eclipse-plugin

Hi i am creating Dynamic Web Project into Eclipse IDE.

Sometimes the Internet is not working properly so at Eclipse displays an error in the console window.

I am a developer so I can view the error, but I need to display the error to the user while they are using this online application.

I have added try..catch blocks for user-friendly display error to user,
but in some of the places I can't Identify the error and Eclipse is displaying an error in the Console.

So I want to display that Console error into user Screen.

There is any way to display Console error to user...??

Comment: What sort of message in the Console? If it is an exception stack trace the only way is to add more try..catch blocks (which is good practice anyway).

Comment: display in console as error "java.net.UnknownHostException:"